# Calling bind method on bind method of a function in JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Just because of curiosity I wanted to make a copy of a function with preset parameters with this particular approach :

```
var x = function (p1,p2) {
    console.log(this, p1, p2);
};
var y = x.bind.bind(this,this,1,2);
y();
```

So, since "bind" method of a function is a function itself, it has a "bind" method and this "bind" method has another "bind" method and so on ...

But when I run my code in Google Chrome it's giving me

> Uncaught TypeError: Bind must be called on a function

So it looks like bind is not a function but

```
typeof x.bind;
```

returns

> function

So I'm trying to understand what really is the type of bind method!
Is that a bug ?

Comment: `x.bind(this).bind(this,1,2);`

Comment: What is `this` in your code? It won't be the same as `x` if that's what you were hoping. `x.bind.bind` is the same as `Function.prototype.bind.bind`, so `x` is lost at that point.

Comment: @Aprillion Yep, `this` from the first `bind` gets overwritten in the second call. I assumed that was the OPs intention, seeing this `x.bind.bind(this,this,1,2);`

Comment: for `Function.prototype.bind.bind(this)()`, Firefox complains `TypeError: Function.prototype.bind called on incompatible target` - perhaps the builtin function itself checks it is not called recursivelly

Comment: @janje You can't overwrite `this` of a "bound" function, [ECMAScript 2015: `Function.prototype.bind` -> Note 2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply), [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf9k7ms5/)

Comment: I just think you're confused by the error message. It's not saying that `bind` is not a function. It's saying that the bind function needs to be *called on* a function. Because you've bound `this` (maybe `window`?) as the `this` value of `bind`, when that bound `bind` is invoked, it complains that its `this` value is not a function. That's what it means by *"called on"*. So `typeof this` is what you should be checking.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks that is good to know.

Comment: @Aprillion Like Bergi said in his answer, you need to bind bind to x `var y = x.bind.bind(x,this,1,2)();   y();`.

Comment: @Aprillion Same as `var y = Function.prototype.bind.bind(x,this,1,2)();  y();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding the `bind` method to `this`, which is not a function. You'll need to bind it to `x` which is the actual function that you're going to use `bind` on:

```
var x = function(p1,p2) {
    console.log(this, p1, p2);
};
var y = x.bind.bind(x);
var z = y(this, 1, 2); // this call is like `x.bind(this, 1, 2)` now
z();
```

Answer (score 0):

`bind` will return the one previous function definition bound to the context designated by the first argument. So `y = x.bind.bind(this,this)` will return the bind function definition bound to `this` and eventually it is like `y = bind(this)` which will throw the exception that you see.

Comment: there is no global `window.bind` function, did you mean `y = Function.prototype.bind.bind(this)` ?

Comment: @Aprillion My assumtion is `x` being a reference to a function definition but then yes `y = x.bind.bind(this,this)` would in fact mean `y = Function.prototype.bind(this)`

Comment: no, `Function.prototype.bind(this)` is something different

Comment: @Aprillion no, `x.bind === Function.prototype.bind` because `bind` is not a function on `x` but is lookup up the prototype chain.

Comment: while `x.bind.bind === Function.prototype.bind`, it has a different effect in the end than `Function.prototype.bind.bind` (`y()` would be undefined instead of the TypeError)